# Why does my code replace the item that has been ordered previously in my CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If the user wishes to "purchase another item", when they do so, the new product will replace the old one in the CSV file.

[This is my blank CSV file when I purchase more than one item; only the latest item purchase goes on the stock file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q0af.png)

[This is my CSV file which contains all the product information:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ZFU.png)

My task is to develop a programme that will update stock levels following an order. In the stock file include a current stock level, re-order level adn target stock level. The programme should, when instructed to do so, calculate which products are out of stock or below the re-order level.

This is my code:

```
import csv

option='yes'
while option=='yes':
    data=open('Product information.csv', 'rt')
    purchase=csv.reader(data)
    blank=open('Blank file.csv', 'wt')
    blank_read=csv.writer(blank)
    order=input('Please enter the GTIN-8 code of the product you would like to purchase: ')
    for row in purchase:
        for field in row:#
            if field==order:
                quantity=int(input('How much of that item: '))
                if quantity<=int(row[3]):
                    print('Your order has successfully been added')
                    difference=int(row[3])-int(row[4])
                    if quantity>=difference:
                        stock=int(row[3])-quantity
                        GTIN=row[0]
                        item=row[1]
                        price=row[2]
                        stock=row[3]
                        reorder=row[4]
                        target_stock=row[5]
                        blank_read.writerows([[GTIN,item,price,stock,reorder,target_stock]])

                    if quantity>int(row[3]):
                        print('You have exceeded the stock level')

    option=input('Do you want to purchase another item: ')
    blank.close()
```

Also, how do I update the most recent stock level onto my blank CSV file, since when the user purchases an item, the current stock will obviously change. Sorry if I am asking for a lot!!!

Thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going through all remaining purchases here:

```
for order in purchase:
    if quantity>=difference:
```

Remove `for order in purchase:` and it should work better:

```
import csv

option='yes'
while option=='yes':
    data=open('Product information.csv', 'rt')
    purchase=csv.reader(data)
    blank=open('Blank file.csv', 'wt')
    blank_read=csv.writer(blank)
    order=input('Please enter the GTIN-8 code of the product you would like to purchase: ')
    for row in purchase:
        for field in row:
            if field==order:
                quantity=int(input('How much of that item: '))
                if quantity<=int(row[3]):
                    print('Your order has successfully been added')
                    difference=int(row[3])-int(row[4])
                    if quantity>=difference:
                        stock=int(row[3])-quantity
                        GTIN=row[0]
                        item=row[1]
                        price=row[2]
                        stock=row[3]
                        reorder=row[4]
                        target_stock=row[5]
                        blank_read.writerows([[GTIN, item, price, stock,
                                              reorder, target_stock]])

                    if quantity>int(row[3]):
                        print('You have exceeded the stock level')

    option=input('Do you want to purchase another item: ')
    blank.close()
```

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks so much for the help. It worked, but I had encountered another problem. Look at the original question; I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I see your question has been answered already by Mike Müller. However, being less knowledgable as Mike I've also spent some time playing around with your question before I figured it out. There are however a few additions I'd like to make to Mike's answer.

First, I'd have to point out your question still isn't as clear to me. At the one hand, you question why you are getting duplicate outputs. Mike has explained and shown you why this is. At the same time though, you state "The programme should, when instructed to do so, calculate which products are out of stock or below the re-order level", which is not exactly what your code is currently doing. Right now it's only withdrawing the amount of required items from the current stock `stock=int(row[3])-quantity`, but only a few lines later the original value is being reset `stock=row[3]` before the new CSV document is written. Even more, if `if quantity<=int(row[3]):` is evaluated as true you print out a message that the order has been added successfully but when `if quantity>=difference:` returned false later on, nothing happens.

Also, you start an if-statement `if quantity<=int(row[3]):` and *within that same* if-statement you call another if-statement `if quantity>int(row[3]):` that cannot be true based upon your first one.

So, I've been messing around with your code and here's my alternative (which is still far from perfect but should offer you some further insights as to how to possibly achieve some of your goals):

```
import csv

blank_file=open('Blank file.csv', 'w')
data_file=open('Product information.csv', 'rt')
do_purchase=csv.reader(data_file)

def makeCSV(user_option):
    if user_option=="yes":
        new_order=input('Please enter the GTIN-8 code of the product you would like to purchase: ')
        global do_purchase
        for row in do_purchase:
            print ("row =", row[0])
            if row[0]== new_order:
                total_quantity=int(row[3])
                reorder_quantity=int(row[4])
                target_quantity=row[5]
                required_quantity=int(input('How much of that item: '))
                if required_quantity<=total_quantity:
                    print("yes")
                    max_order=total_quantity-reorder_quantity
                    if required_quantity<=max_order:
                        stock=total_quantity-required_quantity
                        print("new stock =", stock)
                        GTIN=row[0]
                        item=row[1]
                        price=row[2]
                        reorder=row[4]
                        target_stock=row[5]
                        global blank_file
                        blank_file_read=csv.writer(blank_file)
                        blank_file_read.writerows([[GTIN,item,price,stock,reorder,target_stock]])
                        break
                    else:
                        print('Sorry, we can only deliver', max_order ,'items')
                        break
                else:
                    print("sorry, not enough in stock")
                    break                    
        user_option=input('Do you want to purchase another item: ')
        if user_option == "yes":
            makeCSV("yes")
        else:
            blank_file.close()
            exit
    else:
        blank_file.close()
        exit

makeCSV("yes")
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your code and I ran it but nothing happened; it just stayed blank.

Comment: Hmm. that's a strange one as I had the same problem when I ran your initial code. Maybe we are using different versions of python? You might run 'which python' on the command line to check. I am running python3.5, if you are using a different version, try executing the code with 'python3.5 path/to/the/file/containing/the/code'

Comment: I'm using python 3.3. I'm pretty sure that it is similar in terms of the way they execute the code.

Comment: Well, the code works fine here.. As to the addition to your question, as stated in my initial answer: you are already changing your stock here `stock=int(row[3])-quantity`, however you are resetting it simultaneously when you write `stock=row[3]` just a few lines later. Try removing `stock=row[3]` and your stock levels should change. (PS; that is, as long as the `if required_quantity<=max_order:` condition is met, otherwise (of course) the code will not execute)